# Gateway time-out error when sending a request to the service under the nxginx using subdirectory and SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, curl, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two docker containers, the first one is running a nginx service under the port :80 and the second one is an example project running under the port: 32768.

When I want to type out the domain named `https:...../hawkbit`, I want to access the service as being currently reachable in the domain `http:....:32769`.

I also have a landing page in the main domain.

Nginx should behave as a reverse proxy and offload the SSL process from the services behind it.

I have added a new conf file to the nginx and configured the settings as given below, I can reach the landing page, can reach the service behind separately, but cant reach the service when I type the `https://dev.yusufss.com/hawkbit` which should redirect to request to `http://dev.yusufss.com:32769`

It gives an error `504 Gateway Time-out` after waiting when the `old SSL session ID is stale, removing.` prints to terminal.

Here is the config file of the nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name dev.yusufss.com www.dev.yusufss.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://dev.yusufss.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name dev.yusufss.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/dev.yusufss.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/dev.yusufss.com/privkey.pem;

    location /hawkbit {
        proxy_pass http://dev.yusufss.com:32769/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location / {
        alias /etc/webserver/landing_page/;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

Logs when I send a curl message,
[curl-request-logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1s0J.png)

Nginx logs
[nginx-logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rI7S.png)

Status of docker containers
[docker-containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8GlS.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by opening `port 32769` on the firewall.

In my opinion, since this is closed traffic, there shouldn't be any issue with proxying the request to the service behind it. However, UFW was blocking that request.

I fixed it by using the command below,

```
sudo ufw allow 32769
```